# SQL Server Cursor @@FETCH_STATUS == -1

Tags: sql-server, cursors

I'm using a cursor in a stored procedure. I have to use back to back 2 cursors (not nested). THis is my code:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
     SELECT 
         [Account Id], [Op. Balance], [Cr/Dr], [Total Cr.], [Total Dr.], Balance, [Balance Cr/Dr] 
     FROM 
         AccountBalance(@fld_fy_id)

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ACCOUNT_ID, @OPBAL, @OPCRDR, @TOTALCR, @TOTALDR, @CLBAL, @CLCRDR

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_account_balance_history (fld_fy_id, fld_account_id, fld_opening_balance, fld_op_cr_dr, fld_total_cr, fld_total_dr, fld_closing_balance, fld_cl_cr_dr, fld_is_active, fld_is_delete, fld_created_by)
    VALUES(@fld_fy_id, @ACCOUNT_ID, @OPBAL, @OPCRDR, @TOTALCR, @TOTALDR, @CLBAL, @CLCRDR, 1, 0, @fld_created_by)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ACCOUNT_ID, @OPBAL, @OPCRDR, @TOTALCR, @TOTALDR, @CLBAL, @CLCRDR
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

and immediately after that I'm using a second cursor as below:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
     SELECT 
         [Product Id], Batch, [Opening Qty.], [Receipt Qty.], [Issue Qty.], 
         [Closing Qty.], [Opening Amt.], [Receipt Amt.], [Issue Amt.], 
         [Closing Amt.] 
     FROM 
         ProductBatchwiseStock(@fld_fy_id, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE)

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @PRODUCT_ID, @BATCH, @OPQTY, @RCQTY, @ISSQTY, @CLQTY, @OPAMT, @RCAMT, @ISSAMT, @CLAMT

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_productwise_stock_history (fld_fy_id, fld_product_id, fld_batch, fld_opening_qty, fld_receipt_qty, fld_issue_qty, fld_closing_qty, fld_opening_amt, fld_receipt_amt, fld_issue_amt, fld_closing_amt, fld_is_active, fld_is_delete, fld_created_by)
    VALUES(@fld_fy_id, @PRODUCT_ID, @BATCH, @OPQTY, @RCQTY, @ISSQTY, @CLQTY, @OPAMT, @RCAMT, @ISSAMT, @CLAMT, 1, 0, @fld_created_by)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @PRODUCT_ID, @BATCH, @OPQTY, @RCQTY, @ISSQTY, @CLQTY, @OPAMT, @RCAMT, @ISSAMT, @CLAMT
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

But in the second cursor, I'm getting `@@FETCH_STATUS = -1`, so that part is not executed. I think `@@FETCH_STATUS` is returning the previous cursor status.

Comment: Does your second cursor actually have rows? There's nothing wrong with your syntax, it should work as long as both cursors actually have rows and don't produce any other errors.

Comment: I already tried that but that's not a problem.

Comment: Do you really need to use cursor ? Both query can be done using set-based query

Comment: @ZLK yes, i have 5 rows in second cursor query.

Comment: @Squirrel I always use cursors and even in nested cursors i never get problem.

Comment: You should try to **avoid** cursors if ever possible - and here, it would **most definitely** be possible to handle this with two nice, properly set-based statements and get rid of any of the cursor-related troubles you have .....

Answer (score -1):

`@@FETCH_STATUS` has a global scope and holds the status for all the cursors running in the SQL Server. So, it might be getting updated from another cursor that is running at the same time. Therefore, it might be returning status of another cursor fetch in your cursor loop.

It is advised to avoid using cursors if you can do the same work without using any cursors.

For your help, use the following statements to achieve your task:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_account_balance_history (fld_fy_id, fld_account_id, fld_opening_balance, fld_op_cr_dr, fld_total_cr, fld_total_dr, fld_closing_balance, fld_cl_cr_dr, fld_is_active, fld_is_delete, fld_created_by)
SELECT @fld_fy_id, [Account Id], [Op. Balance], [Cr/Dr], [Total Cr.], [Total Dr.], Balance, [Balance Cr/Dr], 1, 0, @fld_created_by 
FROM AccountBalance(@fld_fy_id)

INSERT INTO tbl_productwise_stock_history (fld_fy_id, fld_product_id, fld_batch, fld_opening_qty, fld_receipt_qty, fld_issue_qty, fld_closing_qty, fld_opening_amt, fld_receipt_amt, fld_issue_amt, fld_closing_amt, fld_is_active, fld_is_delete, fld_created_by)
SELECT @fld_fy_id, [Product Id], Batch, [Opening Qty.], [Receipt Qty.], [Issue Qty.], [Closing Qty.], [Opening Amt.], [Receipt Amt.], [Issue Amt.], [Closing Amt.] , 1, 0, @fld_created_by)
FROM ProductBatchwiseStock(@fld_fy_id, @FROM_DATE, @TO_DATE)
```

Comment: @@FETCH_STATUS is scoped to the connection, NOT globally.